# Comparing 2 objects as if they have numerical values

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

I am going to develop a membership system that would have 7+ levels of user role with many other user feature. For example having 3rd level permission for a city and having 5th level permission for another city.

Is it possible to compare 2 objects as if they have numerical values? For example comparing a user's role against a certain level role.

```
if (objUser.role >= userRole.userLevel3){
    //do something
}
```

The permission rules are way complicated than I briefly explained. So comparing users' role with minimum afford possible is my goal. I am the lead developer of the project and it is my job to provide an easy to use membership system for less experienced developers.

Please consider this question as thinking out loud, I am open to ideas/discussions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# lets you overload comparison operators, so this is definitely possible. You can overload the pair of operators `<` and `>=` (they must be overloaded in pairs), like this:

```
class AccessLevel {
    ...
    public static bool operator <=(AccessLevel x, AccessLevel y) {
        ...
    }
    public static bool operator >(AccessLevel x, AccessLevel y) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write custom comparison operators as `>=` and like are [Overloadable Operators in C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Note that it is rarely good idea to go this route for types that are not strictly "numeric" in regular sense.

For permissions system it may be better to have regular functions or maybe extensions that clearly spell out whether something is allowed or not. It may be hard to spot error due to wrong order of comparison - write some code you feel looks correct and ask other members to explain to you what code means to see if `>=` comparison makes sense in that domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using enums

```
 enum Roles {Role1 = 0, Role2 = 1, Role3 = 2}
 enum UserLevel { Level1 = 0..... Level 10 = 11}
```

You can always cast to a uint and do:

```
  (uint)(object.role) > (uint)(object2.UserLevel)
```

Comment: that is kinda where things get complicated, I dont want to limit us with a specific type. the object (params of struct in my case) might chance and in that case we would have to update every single if statement.